# How to create a copy of kuberenetes resource in the same namespace without having to export it to a yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

We can create a copy of a kuberentes resource by exporting it to a yaml. Then changing the name of the resource and then applying the resource.

Is there an easier way to do that?
Something like

`kubectl copy secret secret-source-name secret-destination-name`

Or any other hacks that devs use.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be done

```
kubectl get resource resource-name -oyaml | yq -i '.metadata.name = "new-name"' | kubectl apply -f -
```

yq: can be installed following https://github.com/clux/whyq#installation

answer credit: https://github.com/clux